# Threading in Python, "communication" between threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping

I have two functions: `def is_updated_database():` is checking if database is updated and the other  one`def scrape_links(database):` is scraping through set of links(that it downloaded from aforementioned database).

So what I want do is when `def is_updated_database():` finds that the updated is downloaded, I want to stop `def scrape_links(database):` and reload it with a new function parameter(`database` which would be a list of new links).

My attempt: I know how to run two threads, but I have no idea how to "connect" them, so that if something happens to one then something should happen to another one.

Comment: Every iteration in `scrape_links()` you should check for some "flag" (global variable, threading.Event, threading.Condition, etc.) and restart in case if flag is set. Database update should cause set of this flag.

Comment: Please post the code for the two functions including the threading part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to solve this problem, may be the checking of database state, and if something new appears there, you could return the new database object, and after that scrape the links, probably this is losing it's multithreading functionality, but that's the way it works.

I don't think that any code examples are required here for you to understand what I mean.